# Tasm how to output register content in binary

Tags: assembly, tasm

Basically, what my program is intended to do, is to output input's each character's ascii code in binary. However, whatever I type in I get 1111111, and it is bugging me out, because I have no clue what could cause the problem
  Here is the code:

```
.model small
.stack 200h

.data
buferis  db 16 dup("z")

.code
pr1:

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax


mov dx, offset buferis
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h 


mov bx, 02h
mov cl, buferis+01h 


mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 10
int 21h


ciklas:
    mov al, [buferis+bx]
    mov ch, 7

    vidinis_ciklas:
        mov dl, '0'
        shl al, 1
        cmp al, 10000000b
        jl toliau
        mov dl, '1'
        toliau:
        int 21h
        dec ch
        cmp ch, 0
        jne vidinis_ciklas

    mov dl, ' '
    int 21h
    inc bx

loop ciklas 

mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 00h
int 21h

end pr1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jl` is signed less-than. As such, `10000000b` is considered to be `-128` which is the smallest signed number on 8 bits, so `al` can never be less than that, hence `jl` never jumps and you get `1` as output. To fix this, you can drop the `cmp` altogether and replace `jl` with `jns`. Remember that `shl` sets flags and the MSB is the sign bit.

Also keep in mind that `cx` is made up of `cl` and `ch`, and that `loop` uses `cx` as counter. Your two loops might thus conflict with each other.

Furthermore, the output function might destroy your value in `al`, so it could be a good idea to save and restore it using `push`/`pop`.

PS: Next time if you require help from others, please comment your code and use english as a courtesy.

Answer (score 3):

After a shift, the shifted-out bit is placed in the carry. So you can just directly do a conditional jump, like

```
...
vidinis_ciklas:
    mov dl, '0'
    shl al, 1    ; moves the MSB into the carry
    jnc toliau   ; jump if carry NOT set
    mov dl, '1'
    toliau:
...
```

Talking about the flags,

```
...
dec ch
; cmp ch, 0 ; <-- this comparison is redundant, DEC sets the zero-flag
jne vidinis_ciklas
...
```